# Forward client's IP address on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, cloud

Our infrastructure is in AWS. all client calls go through API gateway when then forwards the requests to a load balancer, which is connected to an ECS cluster. We have APIs running on that cluster and the job is to aggregate data from multiple third parties.

The problem is that each third party returns different data based on the location.

Eg We are hosted in North Virginia and data is being returned as a request from the United States. However, some calls are coming from Canada, which should return a different data set.

How do we send along with the location of the originating client request to the third party server such that the users get the correct data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a load balancer, your backend servers can get the real client IP from a custom header that the load balancer applies.  As detailed at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html

> **X-Forwarded-For**
>
> The X-Forwarded-For request header helps you identify the IP address
>   of a client when you use an HTTP or HTTPS load balancer. Because load
>   balancers intercept traffic between clients and servers, your server
>   access logs contain only the IP address of the load balancer. To see
>   the IP address of the client, use the X-Forwarded-For request header.
>   Elastic Load Balancing stores the IP address of the client in the
>   X-Forwarded-For request header and passes the header to your server.

So assuming you can get the client IP at your backend servers, you would need to be able to pass the client IP to the service you are calling--so that piece depends on what the service supports.  If the service you are calling doesn't take an explicit input parameter for the IP and then it would require you to spoof the location of the caller, which will be troublesome from an AWS backend server unless you use some custom code to generate the request to the 3rd party service.

Comment: I am making lots of assumptions about what your backend is, how it gets traffic from the real client, and how it may be making API calls to the 3rd party service, so adding more details on the architecture and software used may help yield better info.

Comment: thanks! please see my question above. I have added more details about our backend. @Shawn

Comment: Does the 3rd party API take the IP address as an input parameter, or is it using the request to get the IP address (from something like referrer)?  If it takes an input param, then using the x-forwarded-for header will get you what you need.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't take input param, so x-forwarded-header solution didn' work for us. It appears they take the Ip address from the referer. @Shawn